# Highlight layout after delay?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've created my own compound widget, something just like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView />
  <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm putting 15 of these in a ScrollView. I want it to behave similar to a ListView (I cannot use a ListView directly for this task).

I need the each widget to highlight when pressed. I've gotten this to work, but it's too sensitive - as soon as my finger hits the layout, it highlights - I'd like there to be a delay before highlight to discern between a real tap, and just a scroll gesture.

For example, in ListView, when you drag your finger to scroll, the row items don't get highlighted unless you leave your finger on the row for a second.

This is how I've set the background of each of my compound items:

```
private void setBg() {
  ColorDrawable blr = new ColorDrawable(0xFFFFFFFF);
  Drawable pressed = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);

  StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
  bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET, pressed);
  bg.addState(View.FOCUSED_SELECTED_WINDOW_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, pressed);
  bg.addState(View.PRESSED_ENABLED_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, pressed);
  bg.addState(View.ENABLED_WINDOW_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, pressed);
  bg.addState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, blr);
  bg.addState(View.SELECTED_WINDOW_FOCUSED_STATE_SET, blr);

  setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
}
```

so I'm not sure if I just have set one of the above background drawable states incorrectly - or does ListView do some sort of touch handling internally for that tap delay?

Thanks

Comment: I really really really recommend finding a way to make ListView work for you. It is inconceivable to me that going the path you are going down is somehow easier than using a ListView.

Comment: I understand - my real concern is how fast LsitView can recompose individual rows during fast scrolling. I have composite rows that each have an ImageView, several TextViews, etc - the ImageViews have to be fetched from an image cache. If the user scrolls fast, I need to go fetch these images from the cache to recompose each row. On the other hand, going the way I am now, all the rows are composed once, up front (there is a max of 20 rows). Not sure if it's worth switching.

Comment: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist -- this is an "adapter" that simply holds onto a sack of row Views and serves them up. You do not need to avoid a ListView just because you want to pre-create a fixed number of rows.

Comment: Cool thanks, that's like 99% of what I need. I posted a question to the cw-android google group about it (awaiting moderation). I have one case where I might want to add a view to the adapter, which itself is not focusable, but it has two child buttons which are focusable. I don't think there's a way to handle this situation, where I forward focus from the parent view to the first child button in the layout. I can probably get around that, if you have any ideas that'd be great, but thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Animation or Transition, run animation or transition start when touch down, and stop or reset when touch is up or cancel. Put a delay on the first frame/item in the list.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation

Answer (score 0):

Romain Guy's presentation from Google IO 2009 has been helpful to me in a similar situation:

[Make your Android UI Fast and Efficient](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA)  (about 90 seconds in)

The ViewHolder trick mentioned can help a ton with performance.

Also, showing a temporary Drawable while the image loads from cache can let you scroll fast even if the image hasn't loaded yet, then you can use an animation to (for example) fade in the image when returned from cache.

This seems to be the approach they take in apps such as the Android Market.